# I spent 2.5 months on an VWP, then 5 months on a B1/B2 then 200+ days home in the UK

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I have been employed, and am currently studying for the GRE with the hope of going to grad school in the US. Can anyone see any reason I would not be allowed entry for 6 weeks to travel, visit schools and see friends?

Comment: What happened between the 2.5 months on the visa waiver program and the 5 months on the B-1/B-2 visa?

Comment: Hi Edward, I've edited the title of the question to clarify it, just so you know you were admitted on a visa waiver program, an ESTA is something else

Comment: @pnuts presumably the B-1/B-2 visa is still valid, in which case Edward is not eligible for the VWP or ESTA.  The default duration of validity for British citizens is 10 years.

Comment: @pnuts no, but there's no need for a new ESTA and there's no automatic impact of a visit to Iran (etc.) recently.

Comment: I can think of a few but is there any reason you're concerned?

Comment: @pnuts You could try but there are some objective and some subjective, so no you really can't.  You can try but the question is too subjective IMHO without additional details.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone see any reason I would not be allowed entry for 6 weeks to travel, visit schools and see friends?

From the information you've given, no.  I presume you are a British citizens and that you therefore received a 10-year multiple entry B-1/B-2 visa that is still valid.

You've been out of the country for over 200 days, so it's unlikely that you will be suspected of trying to live in the country.  The reasons for your earlier periods of stay under the VWP and your visa may have an impact on this, however.

There's no reason you should have any trouble with a purpose of investigating graduate schools as a prospective student, nor for visiting friends or sightseeing.

You could of course have trouble on any of several other grounds you haven't raised.  For example, you may be asked to show that you have means to support yourself for a 6-week trip.  If you tell them that you're unemployed (for example, if they ask), you may need to show them how much money you have saved.

Further more, if we allow uninhibited speculation, the answer would certainly be "yes": it is not hard to think of a reason why you *might* be refused entry.

In general, however, the travel pattern you outline in the question will not disqualify you from admission for a six-week trip.

Comment: I think this answer is correct assuming the length of the stays requested when entering for the last two visits were pretty close to 2.5 and 5 months, respectively. Frequent visitors with a record of repeatedly staying significantly longer than they request on entry can sometimes have problems on a subsequent entry.